# Python - If I remove Lambda then app is undefined?

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter

This code works fine.

```
CalculateButton = tk.Button(self.root, text="Calculate", command=lambda: calc.GrandTotal()).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
```

But this code results in an error: "NameError: global name 'app' is not defined"

```
CalculateButton = tk.Button(self.root, text="Calculate", command=calc.GrandTotal()).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
```

So why is it that removing Lambda causes an error?

Source code itself is:

```
    # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

# Classes
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        # Create G.U.I. Framework
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.root.title("Job Estimator")
        self.root.geometry("290x152")
        self.root.resizable(0,0)

        # Create G.U.I. Widgets
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Labour:   "   + unichr(163) + "40.00 x Hours")  .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Travel:     " + unichr(163) + "1.00   x Miles") .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Plastic:    " + unichr(163) + "2.00   x Metres").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Copper:  "    + unichr(163) + "3.00   x Metres").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Chrome: "     + unichr(163) + "4.00  x Metres") .grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        tk.Label(self.root, text="Total: "      + unichr(163))                    .grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W)

        self.totalLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="0.00")
        self.totalLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=42, pady=0)

        self.LabourInput = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.LabourInput.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.LabourInput.insert(0, "0")

        self.TravelInput = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.TravelInput.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.TravelInput.insert(0, "0")

        self.PlasticInput = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.PlasticInput.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.PlasticInput.insert(0, "0")

        self.CopperInput = tk.Entry(self.root)        
        self.CopperInput.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.CopperInput.insert(0, "0")

        self.ChromeInput = tk.Entry(self.root)        
        self.ChromeInput.grid(row=4, column=1)     
        self.ChromeInput.insert(0, "0")

        CalculateButton = tk.Button(self.root, text="Calculate", command=calc.GrandTotal()).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

class Calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Multiply(self, number, rate):
        try:
            NumFloat = float(number)
            RateFloat = float(rate)
            return NumFloat * RateFloat
        except (ValueError):
            raise tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "One or more text fields contains non-numerical characters.")

    def GrandTotal(self): # Adds each entry field to produce and return a grand total. 

        # Set Variables
        self.LabourTotal   = self.Multiply(app.LabourInput. get(), 40)
        self.TravelTotal   = self.Multiply(app.TravelInput. get(), 1)
        self.PlasticTotal  = self.Multiply(app.PlasticInput.get(), 2)
        self.CopperTotal   = self.Multiply(app.CopperInput. get(), 3)
        self.ChromeTotal   = self.Multiply(app.ChromeInput. get(), 4)

        self.CompleteTotal = self.LabourTotal + self.TravelTotal + self.PlasticTotal + self.CopperTotal + self.ChromeTotal

        return app.totalLabel.config(text=self.CompleteTotal) # Return the total value.

calc = Calculator()
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app` is not defined until after the `Application()` instance is created, which means that `Application.__init__` must have completed *first*.

By removing the `lambda`, you **directly** call the `calc.GrandTotal()` method, and that method relies on `app` already existing. It does not, as `Application.__init__` is not done yet.

The whole point of the `command` argument however is to pass in something that will be called *later*. That's why the `lambda` works, it produces a function to call `calc.GrantTotal()` later on, when the *Calculate* button is pressed. By calling it directly you short-circuited this normal path.

You *can* pass in `calc.GrantTotal` *without* calling it, by removing the `()`:

```
CalculateButton = tk.Button(
    self.root, text="Calculate", command=calc.GrandTotal)
CalculateButton.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
```

Note that I called the `Button.grid()` method in a separate expression. `Button.grid()` returns `None`; there is no point in storing that return value in a variable. Store the `tk.Button()` return value instead.

Comment: Thank you. That explained it perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` is used to create a function that, when called (i.e., when you click the button), will call `calc.GrandTotal`. Without it, you are assigning the return value of an immediate call to `GrantTotal` instead as the callback.